# Sub folder mapping in reactJS production

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

I'm using ConnectedRouter **ConnectedRouter history={history}** and history has **const history = createHistory({basename:"/url"})** in the router version react-**router-redux": "^5.0.0** the problem is I am having two folders and I deployed both folders I differentiated the folders in index.js

`app.get("/", function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../build/index.html"));
      });`

```
  app.get("/seller/*", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../build/seller/index.html"));
  });`
```

the problem is first react folder is mapped correctly but second folder appears as blank when i give the URL specified

Comment: Change res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../build/seller/index.html")); to res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../build/index.html"));

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the above issue by adding changes in package.json  **"homepage": "http://domainurl/seller"**, by adding this line the homepage command in the package json maps for the baseURL you need